# Can we include a third parameter inside define function?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I saw code in RequireJS where `define()` contains a third parameter other than dependency modules and callback function. Can we include a third parameter inside the `define` function? Code:

```
define("app/tmpl/mainTmpl", ["ax/ext/ui/Button",
                  "ax/ext/ui/Label", "ax/ext/ui/Layout"], 
    function (Button, Label, Layout) {
        return function () {
            return {
                //some code
            };
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter in your example code is the **module name** (AKA module id) you may optionally pass to `define()`. It's not recommended to set the name explicitly under normal circumstances. If omitted, a name is inferred and assigned by the AMD loader or it might be generated by the [optimization tool](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html) of RequireJS. See [this section](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#modulename) of the official RequireJS API docs or the [AMD API spec](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki/AMD).

Comment: Thanks a lot @matthias.I didn't went through the docs properly.